# How to check for sql injection attack?

Tags: web-application, appsec, sql-injection

We do our final year project related to sql injection. For implementing sql injection attack which IDE or tool we used?  bcoz netbeans and other type of IDE are more secured?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question completely, but I'll try to answer.

> How to check for sql injection attack

The de-facto standard tool is [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/). It is a very powerful tool and is thoroughly documented.

> which IDE or tool we used?  bcoz netbeans and other type of IDE are more secured?

NetBeans (or any other IDE) has absolutely nothing to do with sql injections. It is a job of a web developer to make sure he produces secure code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..sqlmap is used for detection and prevention of sql attack....but we want to know how sql injection attack is performed for our own application....do U got my question?

Comment: If you have the source code, a code review would be better.

Comment: @Kavitha, do a code review, as Gumbo suggested. Carefully examine every SQL query in your application. Does it receives user-supplied data? Is this data properly sanitized?

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether the data is user-supplied or not. Just treat every parameter value the same regardless of their origin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this covers exactly what you ask for, but here is something at least.

Using a vulerability discovery tool like Nikto, Nessus, Nexpose, MSF or others to scan for injections will probably discover some injectable pages, but it's likely it won't be able to detect security issues as well.

Using tools + manuel testing seem to be the best option for most cases.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got your question, you need to know if your code is secure to sql injection or not. For that you need to use tools like sqlmap or havij or you can try vulnerability assessment tools like Acunetix,OWASP ZAP or burp-suite, so with them you can inject check if your database is vulnerable to this attack. Read more about secure coding on OWASP and SANS web application development. Netbeans do not provide you with capability to check if your code is injectable or not.
Hope this links will help you in what you looking for.

```
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OTG-INPVAL-005%29

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

http://www.veracode.com/directory/cwe-sans-top-25
```

Also look for **Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA)**, if you want see example of vulnerable coding.

```
http://www.dvwa.co.uk/
```